# Не правильно вычисляется синус. JS

Tags: javascript, математика

в программе надо найти синус и косинус числа, имея угол (не в радианах) вычисляю косинус: `Math.cos(num * Math.PI / 180)` - значение правильное, с синусом: `Math.sin(num * Math.PI / 180)` - все правильно, пока не доходит до 180 или -180 - возвращает результат `1.224....` и т.д., что 100% неверно. Что делать? в чем ошибка

Comment: что значит _пока не доходит к 180 или -180 - возвращает результат 1.224_? При каких выходных параметрах ты получаешь неверный результат?

Comment: @Grundy если -180<num<180 то все верно, если же =180 или =(-180) то значение 1.224... и -1224... соответственно

Comment: ты неправильно смотришь возвращаемое значение: `1.2246467991473532e-16` - `e-16` показывает что число перед `e` нужно умножить на 10 в степени -16 - в данном случае это эквивалент 0. Убедиться в этом можно применив `.toFixed` к результату

Comment: @Grundy ага. ок, и как тогда сделать чтоб возвращало 0?

Comment: никак, это нормальное число. стандартная ошибка округления

Comment: @Grundy хорошо, спасибо. Напишите ответ, приму